# Could a "fuzzy", or non-symmetric, relationship change the size of a power set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's say we have a set of numbers called the Unnatural Numbers (UN). These numbers have the following properties.

- They're equinumerous with the natural numbers
- They have no defined position
- They have no defined value
- The well ordering principle doesn't apply
- They have just enough "distinctness" that we can add n UNs to a set and have the set contain n members

I think of them like a countably infinite pile of absolutely identical grains of sand.

The power set of the UNs seems to be countably infinite, which is the same size as the set of UN. This seems to be because the relationships between the UNs are low. My questions are:

1. What am I getting wrong?
2. Can power sets be used as a measure of how many relationships there are or is there a better way to do it?
3. Can relationships be made "fuzzy", or non-symmetrical, and what does that do to power sets?

Regarding (3), there seems to be no issue numerically, but I can't really work out what it means. Does a "fuzzy" relationship only carry certain properties, would this mean that subsets we think of as distinct would now be the same, would the power set only change under certain conditions, etc.

I may be talking complete nonsense with this, but it's been fun thinking about what "fuzziness" could mean.

Comment: "The power set of the UNs seems to be countably infinite" -- could you please expound here?

Comment: How does one size $n$-"set" of UN's compare to another size $n$-"set" of UN's?  Are these "equal"?  If they might not be "equal", in what way can we actually say so and how can we not use that information to actually define values on them?  If they are equal, then wouldn't the "power set" just consist of "sets" of the form $\{0\bullet\},\{1\bullet\},\{2\bullet\},\{3\bullet\},\dots,\{n\bullet\},\dots$ where $\{n\bullet\}$ is the "set" with $n$ UN's.

Comment: Y. Forman, as I see it a subset that contains 3 members is exactly the same as every other member that contains 3 members, which means there's only 1 subset for each number of members, and only 1 infinite subset.

Comment: JMoravitz, what I was trying to do is remove as much "distinctness" as possible, but perhaps a set of n elements, is different in some way to another set of n elements, I just don't see how without adding something

Comment: Well., if you do, then you'll likely arrive at a set of $1$ element is different in some way to another set of $1$ element, thus allowing us to form a bijection with $\Bbb N$.  It will not be an order-preserving bijection, but we don't care about keeping track of an order on the UN's, and without an order the "position" of them as well as the wellordering principle can't be talked about for them.  It sounds as though you are talking about [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) and counting how many sub-multisets exist.  For finite sets this is a common problem in combinatorics.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a zombie response to a two-year-old question, but it seems to me that the OP here reinvented/rediscovered the concepts of [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) **and** [equivalence classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class), restricted to the set of natural numbers $\Bbb{N}_0 := \{0, 1, 2, 3, ...\}$. From OP's comments:

> as I see it a subset that contains 3 members is exactly the same as every other member that contains 3 members, which means there's only 1 subset for each number of members, and only 1 infinite subset.

In other words, OP is really suggesting that 2 subsets of the "Unnatural Numbers" are to be considered "the same" if they can be [paired off in a 1-1 correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection). This is functionally equivalent to taking the subsets of the regular natural numbers $\Bbb{N}_0$ and [forgetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forgetful_functor) the (labels/values/numerical properties) on the elements of any subset.

If we do this, then the only way to tell two subsets of $\Bbb{N}_0$ apart is if they have different numbers of elements. Contrapositively, this is the same as saying two subsets of $\Bbb{N}_0$ are "the same" if they have the same number of elements (i.e. there's a bijection between them). "Indistinguishability", in this sense, turns out to define what is usually referred to as an *equivalence relation* $\sim$ on the subsets of $\Bbb{N}_0$. Although OP specifies "fuzziness" to mean non-symmetric in their post, their example of "fuzziness" is more like the "forgetfulness" one gets from an equivalence relation--we can indeed check that "indistinguishability" is an equivalence relation on subsets of $\Bbb{N}_0$, which actually means it's symmetric (as well as reflexive and transitive). And the names of these equivalence classes are exactly the finite and countable cardinalities, because "cardinal numbers" are *exactly* what one gets by "forgetting" the labels, or interpretations, or relationships, between the elements of a set, and just keeping its "size".

*(The process of "forgetting" some or all irrelevant aspects of the structure on a highly structured set is very common in math and plays a role in foundations: see, for instance, [forgetful functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forgetful_functor). I suppose this could be considered another topic the OP 'discovered' for themselves, in a particular context.)*

Comment: I'd completely forgotten about this :) What I was playing around with at the time was "information". The basic notion was that different definitions change what kind of things we can do with an object. The power set of UN, if we don't apply external structure, isn't the same as N. This implied to me that some sort of "information" contained in the definitions was being encoded, in a sense, in the structure and the power set was a way of quantifying it. This raised questions. Let's say the "informational units" in the defs are discrete, can they be continuous (fuzzy)?

Answer (score 0):

You're really ignoring the following thing:

> If $f\colon A\to B$ is a bijection, then $F(X)=\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}$ defines a bijection between $\mathcal P(A)$ and $\mathcal P(B)$. In other words, equinumerous sets have equinumerous power sets.

What you sort of alleging here is that because your set lacks structure, it only has "a few subsets". But just because it lacks structure doesn't mean that it can be endowed with structure.

For example $\Bbb N$ lacks the structure of a field, but it can be endowed with one by pulling it from a different countable set. For example the rational numbers.

Of course, this ignores a more serious problem, that not all subsets are necessarily definable in a fixed structure. Even in the case of the natural numbers, not all subsets are definable. **Most** subsets are not definable.

What you might be looking for is the collection of definable subsets of a given structure. Then on a fixed countable set there can be many ways to structure it, and ask what sort of sets are definable in a fixed structure. This acts *a bit* like a power set, but not quite exactly that.

---

Let's leave, for a second, the land of countable sets. And leave the axiom of choice behind. Without the axiom of choice you get sets which can have actual limitations on what kind of structures can be put on them. You can find sets that cannot be endowed with a structure of a field, or a linear order, and so on and so forth.

In some cases this in fact leads to this sort of "intuitive" thought that the only subsets you can have are finite or complement of finite sets. Such sets are called *amorphous sets* and they are a rich source for counterexamples in failures related to choice.

Comment: I see no issue applying another structure to it, but unlike the natural numbers that structure isn't contained in its relationships. The bijection implies capacity, certainly, but if you can't tell one set of 3 apart from another set of 3, how are they inherently distinct? Can they be inherently distinct or do we have to apply an artificial structure to them? What I'm interested in is more what we can build based on the relationships rather than what can be built if we apply artificial relationships. Hopefully, that made some sense

Comment: Yes. You've hit on a well-known truth. Questions of *cardinality* are *invariant* under changing the elements, and their answer depend only on the cardinality. All singletons are of size $1$.

Comment: That gives me something to look up, thank you. I'm pretty sure I'm not conveying what I want to actually know lol. So is there any way to make the inherent structure "fuzzy", and in so doing, change the number of distinct subsets you can get?

Comment: You seem to mean that you want to remove some of the structure, or replace it with a different structure.

Comment: Possibly yes. Possibly just softening the ability to know if subsets are distinct from each other could work. Honestly, I'm struggling to articulate this well, so anything vaguely related I could read would be awesome.

Comment: Yes, you are being very vague and inarticulate. I am not entirely sure what you mean, or what you mean by "distinct". Two things exist, they are the same or distinct.

Comment: And you can know that based on something like an axiom. 1 is distinct from 2 because we've defined it that way and we can know it's distinct because of those definitions. What if we couldn't fully know? Perhaps something like this - I've transmitted to you a "1" and you know that it's the output of an XOR gate, you also know that 1 of the inputs must have been 1, but you can't know which input. I send you a stream of data and I want you to put them in input subsets. Instead of 4 (one for each possible input config) distinct sets, you could have 2 distinct subsets, or maybe 4 fuzzy sets

Comment: I think that your ideas are coming from a naive view of mathematics. The only way you can learn this is to properly learn basic logic and set theory. Not by "reading something vaguely related", but by properly understanding the underlying concepts. Because it seems to me that the questions you're asking have simple answers, but you currently don't have the language necessary for clearly stating these questions, and maybe also not enough knowledge to fully understand the answer. Start with Enderton's books about logic and set theory.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. The notion came up when I was playing around with different infinities and what could be encoded in them. Different "concepts" need "larger" infinities and it very much seemed that something similar to Shannon entropy was going on only with structures instead of bits. Then I got thinking about minimum structures required for "concepts" and here we are with me trying to find the words for these ideas so I can learn more about them.